# Как сделать так, чтобы данные в цикле каждый раз добавлялись в массив

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Я очень туплю и не могу понять как в массив или в лист или в коллекцию сохранить результат каждого прохода цикла, а только потом это передать во View.
Соответственно 
**код контроллера:**

```
foreach (var k in db.Sources.Where(c => c.id != null).Select(c => c.URL))
{

//какая то логика

     var RSSFeedData = (from x in xml.Descendants("item")
     select new RSSFeed
     {
        Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
        Link = (string)x.Element("link"),
        RSSName = (string)x.Element("Name"),
        PubDate = (string)x.Element("pubDate")
                               });

ViewBag.RSSFeed = RSSFeedData;

}
return view();
```

я пробовал вот так:
     `ViewBag.RSSFeed = ViewBag.RSSFeed.Add(RSSFeedData);`
не работает. Пытался создать массив, с типом string, но там тоже не получается присвоить RSSFeed. с листом тоже самое.

```
   <tbody>

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.RSSFeed)
  {
   <tr>
     <td><a href="@item.Link">@item.Title</a></td>
     <td>@item.RSSName</td>
     <td>@item.PubDate</td>
   </tr>
   }
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты в каждом цикле перезаписываешь ViewBag.RSSFeed. Ко времени формирования View ViewBag.RSSFeed будет содержать последний записанный элемент.

Убедись что в RSSFeedData записывается не пустое значение.

Пример для списка string (или любого другого класса):

Controller:

```
List<string> Items = new List<string>();
var Sources = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
foreach(var k in Sources)
{
    Items.Add("Template "+ k);
}
ViewBag.Items = Items;
return View();
```

View:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Item)
    {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: var Sources = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
Можете рассказать что в этой строке происходит?
и у меня во View уже есть такой цикл, если я поменяю RSSFeed на Items, то компилятор ругается что не может определить элементы 
`@foreach (var item in ViewBag.RSSFeed)
           {
              <tr>
          <td><a href="@item.Link">@item.Title</a></td>
          <td>@item.RSSName</td>
          <td>@item.PubDate</td>
             </tr>
             }`

Comment: я добавил в нормальном виде код в вопрос, и так же изменил цикл немного в контроллере, чтобы показать что я беру какие то данные из бд

Comment: `var Sources = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5}; ` - Формируется список из 5 элементов типа int. `var RSSFeedData = new List<RSSFeed>();` до цикла. В цикле `RSSFeedData.Add();`  И `ViewBag.RSSFeed = RSSFeedData;` после цикла перед непосредственным формированием View. 
Последним действием, динамически создается свойство RSSFeed в объекте ViewBag. Если свойство не создано на View оно не будет найдено и выдаст ошибку.

Comment: извини что так докапываюсь, но появились две ошибки, `'IEnumerable<RSSFeed>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<RSSFeed>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`                      
и `A local or parameter named 'RSSFeedData' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter BDParser`

Comment: 1. Add принимает 1 элемент - ты пытаешься впихать IEnumiranle, что является перечислением. Используй AddRange или записывай по 1.
2. Почитай ошибку внимательнее, а потом переименуй переменную.

Comment: Да, я разобрался, наконец-то, спасибо за помощь